# flash based spreadsheet

Tags: flash, open-source, spreadsheet

Is there any open source flash based spreadsheet application like google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any Flash-based free software spreadsheet. However, there are several spreadsheets using AJAX. See e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_spreadsheet) for a list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything like this in Flash either, and I would be really surpised if it would be one!

The only thing you can do with Flash ist to parse a XLS file into your application.
To do that, you can use this framework: http://github.com/djw/as3xls